# GWT - Google visualization problems using layout panels?

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I'm having troubles in my GWT app with a Google Visualization chart not showing up until after the user has some sort of interaction with the window (e.g. moves the mouse across the screen or presses a button). This would be fine except that the chart is suppose to show up as the first thing the user sees and since it's meant to be seen on a mobile device, it's likely they will not see the chart because their first interaction will be clicking a button that hides the chart to show other information.

Using the ["Getting started tutorial"](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted#A_Simple_Interactive_Chart) over at the Visualization code's page, the chart loads immediately fine (once some slight changes are made the fix the problems from the slightly out of date tutorial). After some trial and error to find where the difference between my code and the example code that was causing the problem, I found that it's happening because my code is using the newer layout panels instead of just regular panels in GWT.

The below code is the working tutorial code changed so that it uses a RootLayoutPanel.get() instead of a RootPanel.get(). With this, the chart doesn't load until you click to reload the page, then you can see the chart for an instant before the page reloads. This should be easily tested with the below code. To get the chart to show up for the entire time, simply change RootLayoutPanel.get() to RootPanel.get().

Something in my app is allowing the chart to load after user interaction (I'm not sure what). However, the layout panel is certainly the problem as if I change it to a regular panel it works fine. Unfortunately, my entire app is built using layout panels.

What's going on and how might I be able to make the chart show up from the start using layout panels? Thank you much!

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.Selection;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.events.SelectHandler;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options;

public class SimpleViz implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a callback to be called when the visualization API
    // has been loaded.
    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        LayoutPanel panel = RootLayoutPanel.get();

        // Create a pie chart visualization.
        PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());

        pie.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
        panel.add(pie);
      }
    };

    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
    // when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
  }

  private Options createOptions() {
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setWidth(400);
    options.setHeight(240);
    options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
    return options;
  }

  private SelectHandler createSelectHandler(final PieChart chart) {
    return new SelectHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        String message = "";

        // May be multiple selections.
        JsArray<Selection> selections = chart.getSelections();

        for (int i = 0; i < selections.length(); i++) {
          // add a new line for each selection
          message += i == 0 ? "" : "\n";

          Selection selection = selections.get(i);

          if (selection.isCell()) {
            // isCell() returns true if a cell has been selected.

            // getRow() returns the row number of the selected cell.
            int row = selection.getRow();
            // getColumn() returns the column number of the selected cell.
            int column = selection.getColumn();
            message += "cell " + row + ":" + column + " selected";
          } else if (selection.isRow()) {
            // isRow() returns true if an entire row has been selected.

            // getRow() returns the row number of the selected row.
            int row = selection.getRow();
            message += "row " + row + " selected";
          } else {
            // unreachable
            message += "Pie chart selections should be either row selections or cell selections.";
            message += "  Other visualizations support column selections as well.";
          }
        }

        Window.alert(message);
      }
    };
  }

  private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
    data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
    data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
    data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Layout panels the sizing of the widgets is done in JavaScript. When the initial page is loaded the initial sizing is done after everything else is finished. However in your case the pie is added when the library is loaded and that runs after the initial sizing. Therefor your widget isn't sized and won't show up. You need to call `panel.forceLayout();` explicitly as the last method in you run method.

Answer (score 0):

The google chart tools definately work with `LayoutPanels`. I am using it myself.

It's really difficult to say what's wrong but here are a couple of suggestions:

- Check with Chrome Dev Tools (Console) if an exception is thrown.
- Do you have [standard mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) enabled. That's important with `LayoutPanels` (make sure you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your HTML host page
- You could try a 3rd party [wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/) (supports automatic resizes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I certainly get the chart tools to work with LayoutPanels, but the problem is how they work. Specifically, the strange way in which the interaction is needed. Did you happen to test the example code I've got? I know that's a bit of a hassle to setup a new GWT project and plug in my code just to answer my question, but it should be able to show my problem in detail. I do also have standard mode enabled. And the third party wrapper could cause the chart to appear without the user interaction, but I'd like to avoid adding another third party thing if I can.

Comment: Usually no interaction is needed and the chart should be displayed right away. Can you mabye update your post with two screens that show the issue ? Also which version of GWT are you using and which one of the google chart wrapper ?